# Unable to build OpenCV from source

Tags: c++, c, opencv, cmake, makefile

I tried following [these instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) to build OpenCV from the source code, but it keeps failing at about 17%. I created a temporary build directory, ran `cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`
followed by `make` when the following error pops up.

I tried building this inside of a clean build directory, running it as sudo, and deleting the CMakeCache.txt file (someone having a similair error said it helped).

```
[ 17%] Built target opencv_hal_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_hal
[ 17%] Built target opencv_hal
[ 17%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[ 17%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 17%] Built target opencv_core
[ 17%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[ 17%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[ 17%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgcodecs
[ 17%] Built target opencv_imgcodecs
[ 17%] Built target opencv_videoio_pch_dephelp
[ 17%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_videoio
[ 17%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:285: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.3.0.0' failed
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4401: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

Comment: You basically **never** need to build software as root and you shouldn't do that. Is there a way to get cmake to be more verbose about what it is doing during the build? There's no information there about what might possibly have failed (unless there's a log file somewhere).

Comment: Sudo only for make install, for make take a normal user. Was configuration complete or were dependencies missing? Using make VERBOSE=1 gives more details.

Comment: Yeah the attempt at running all of it as root was just as an act of desperation

Here is the verbose output

https://gist.github.com/AhmedSamara/be794682cbce29d0cd70

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: After two days of trying to install opencv I'm wondering if it wouldn't be easier to just "roll your own". Why should the install be so difficult for a million different reasons even on lts releases of a major distro like ubuntu. For my use case, and I imagine many others, we need just a small fraction of the functionality and an irrelevant portion is failing to build. This wonderful library shouldnt be such a pain in the ass to install. If the install is so hard why should we feel confident in the algorithms contained inside? Okay done venting.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug of gcc-6.1, downgrade your gcc to gcc-5.3.

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5.3 g++-5.3
rm /usr/bin/gcc
ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-5 /usr/bin/gcc
rm /usr/bin/g++
ln -s /usr/bin/g++-5 /usr/bin/g++
```

Now, you can use cmake again.

Comment: If it is a known bug of gcc6.1 could you link to the corresponding bug-tracker entry?